# Ocultar y mostrar un <th> junto con su <td> en determinada condición JQuery, PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tengo una tabla que muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta tabla es una proyección del día a día ingresada por el usuario partiendo de hoy, es decir el usuario ingresa en un input hasta que mes quiere la proyección termine.

Este es el código en php donde aumento día a día con un for, lo multiplico por 30 por ser los días del mes.
Si el user ingresa 1, el for genera 30 días, si ingresa 2 el for genera 60 días, etc..

```
 <?php $fechacontoler = $query->getFechaActual();
            foreach($fechacontoler as $fechacontolers){
                $meses_a_mostrar = (int)$_POST['mesesamostrar'];
                $DiasCal = $meses_a_mostrar * 30;
                //VARIABLE DE FECHA TRAIDA DE MYSQL
                global  $fechaActualMysql;
                $fechaActualMysql = $fechacontolers['fecha_actual'];
                // VISTA CON TODOS LOS MESES
            for ($i=0; $i < $DiasCal; $i++) { 
              $fechaAMostrar = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fechaActualMysql."+ $i"." day"));?>
                <th class="dias header center" style="display:none;"><?php echo $fechaAMostrar ?></th>
                <?php }
```

Por defecto mi encabezado de fechas generadas esta oculto con un hidden y la idea es que al hacer click a un botón el me muestre solo los días 30 de cada mes en esa proyección, los demás días me los oculte.

No solo el encabezado, también el resto de la columna, prácticamente la columna completa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté recorrer todos los  y realizar algo así pero no funcionó:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
     $('table tr:first th').each(function() {
                // Obtengo el valor de dicho th
                var value = $(this).text();
                
                if (value == '2021-10-30') {
                    $('.datos').show();
                }
                // alert(value);
            });
    
});
```

EN definitiva quiero mostrar solo los 30 días de cada mes y el resto ocultarlos.

Answer (score 1):

A la hora de armar desde PHP tu HTML crea en los dias 30 de cada mes una clase que sea especial para estos dias. Desde PHP seria solo saber si es día 30 por a variable que obtienes sino la tendrás que leer y con una condición if() decides si imprimir en el html con echo "" la clase .dia_30_de_mes

Luego desde tu codigo en jQuery solo debes decirle que le haga show a estas clases

```
$('.dias').hide();  // esta seria la clase común para todos los elementos de tu tabla
$('.dia_30_de_mes').show();
```

Primero los ocultas todos y después muestras solos los del día 30.

Existe mejores soluciones para esto como traer de la db con sql las fechas solo de dias 30 con WHERE y tal y usando ajax para reescribir la tabla HTML con los valores de devolución de tu controlador en PHP, pero no se que tanto estarías dispuesto a editar tu código, no obstante este método te funcionara perfectamente